# Show histortical results from same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `MyHistory` my history have about 1000 rows in this table and the performance is crappy at best.

What I want to do is select rows showing the next row as a result.  This is probably a bad example.

this is MyHistory structure `ID int,DateTimeColumn datetime,ValueResult decimal (4,2)`

my table has the following data
`ID|DateTimeColumn|ValueResult`
`1|8/1/2005 1:01:29 PM|2`
`1|8/1/2006 1:01:29 PM|3`
`1|8/1/2007 1:01:29 PM|5`
`1|8/1/2008 1:01:29 PM|9`

What I want to do is select out of this the following data
`ID|DateTimeColumn|ValueResult|ChangeValue`
`1|8/1/2008 1:01:29 PM|9|4`
`1|8/1/2007 1:01:29 PM|5|2`
`1|8/1/2006 1:01:29 PM|3|1`
`1|8/1/2005 1:01:29 PM|2|`

You'll notice that ID is = ID and the datetime column is now desc.  Thats the easy part.  But how do I make a self referencing table (in order to calculate the difference in value) based on which datetime comes next?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calculating this Change value ??

Answer (score 0):

So, the task is:

- to order records by `DateTimeColumn` descending,
- to set sequence number for each record to identify next record,
- to calculate required difference in value.

This is one of many possible solutions:

```sql
-- Use CTE to make intermediate table with sequence numbers - ranks
;WITH a (rank, ID, DateTimeColumn, ValueResult) AS
(
    select rank() OVER (ORDER BY m.DateTimeColumn DESC) as rank, ID, DateTimeColumn, ValueResult
    from MyHistory
)
-- Select all resulting columns
select a1.ID,
       a1.DateTimeColumn,
       a1.ValueResult,
       a1.ValueResult - a2.ValueResult as ChangeValue    -- Difference between current record and next one
  from a a1
      join a a2
          on a2.rank = a1.rank + 1   -- linking next record to each one
```